# Email alias from LegacyExchangeDN - LDAP

Tags: ldap, exchangewebservices

I am working with Exchange EWS API. The API returns me a value which is legacyExchangeDN. The value looks like this -

```
/o=Amazon/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDXXXXXXXXDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=b08141c097dfd32432klbva43595-email-list
```

The value is also cropped in some cases (last few characters are not returned by the API)

How can I convert this value into meaningful email address?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would see this when you make a findItems request because Exchange doesn't resolve the Native (EX) Addresses back to SMTP addresses in this operation. So if you make a GetItem (or Load/Loadpropertiesforitems) request on the particular item you want to look at it as long as that address can be resolve in the GAL (eg that user or object hasn't been deleted) it should return the resolved address. The other option is to use the ResolveName operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn645423(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: I was not able to get this working for my use case. ResolveName does not seem to work for random strings like /o=Amazon/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDXXXXXXXXDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=b08141c097dfd32432klbva43595-email-list

Comment: a random string won't work, if you read the documentation for ResolveName it will only resolve those items that are visible in the Global Address List. Eg say you have a Message from a Mailbox that was deleted it won't be able to resolve this address etc

Comment: That is actually the legacyExchangeDN property (also set in LDAP for every email enabled Exchange account)not really a random string. Not sure if resolveNames is able to resolve it.

Comment: If you use GetItem does the address get resolved ? It sounds like its not visible in the Gal